# How to append text to the end of a file as root user?

Tags: bash, sudo

So I'm trying to create a install script for my raspberries, first thing is to give them a static IP.

```
echo -e "Enter static IP"
read static_ip

echo -e "Enter DNS IP"
read dns_ip

echo -e ""
echo -e "The following settings will be set"

echo -e "\e[32mStatic IP:\e[0m\t${static_ip}"
echo -e "\e[32mDNS IP:\e[0m\t${dns_ip}"

sudo echo "interface wlan0" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf
sudo echo "static ip_address=${static_ip}/24" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf
sudo echo "static routers=${dns_ip}" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf
sudo echo "static domain_name_servers=${dns_ip}" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

But it keeps saying "permission denied", I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `sudo echo … >> …` The redirection (`>>`) is set up by the shell before `sudo` is started. If `echo` was about to open the file by itself, it could; but it is about to start with stdout inherited from `sudo`, which in turn starts with stdin set up by the invoking shell. The error you got means the shell was denied access to the file.

Use `sudo tee`. The point is `tee` can open files by itself:

```
echo "something" | sudo tee -a /output/file > /dev/null
```

This way `tee` will append (`-a`) the text to the `/output/file` with proper permissions.

`tee` is designed to pass its input and duplicate it (in general: multiply). In this case one copy goes to the file and the other travels along the pipe. Since we only need the first one, we redirect the second copy to `/dev/null` so it doesn't appear in the console. Everything that goes to `/dev/null` vanishes.

Comment: Worked like a charm, one question tho, what does /dev/null do right here?

Comment: @killstreet I have expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it in a subshell to make the redirection work.

sudo sh -c echo "string" >> file

[ from sudo man page: examples ]

Comment: This won't work, the redirection is still parsed by the outer shell. You have to quote properly, like `sudo sh -c 'echo "string" >> file'`.