# Trying to write to /sys/class/gpio/export – write error: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, io

I have an Intel aaeon upboard and I want to use its GPIO pins. To do that I'm trying the below code:

```
echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

But when I run it, this is what I get:

```
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

---

The output of `ls /sys/class/gpio/`:

```
export gpiochip225 gpiochip228 gpiochip314 gpiochip341 gpiochip414 unexport
```

Comment: Have you configured the kernel for GPIO? See for example [this link](https://www.emcraft.com/stm32f429discovery/controlling-gpio-from-linux-user-space).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yeah i have gpiochip225, gpiochip228, such files. I really dont know why not working

Comment: @harrymc how can I reach from terminal to configure kernel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt) reads:

> GPIO controllers have paths like `/sys/class/gpio/gpiochip42/` (for the
>   controller implementing GPIOs starting at #42) and have the following
>   read-only attributes:
>
> `/sys/class/gpio/gpiochipN/`
>
> `base` ... same as `N`, the first GPIO managed by this chip
>
> […]
>
> `ngpio` ... how many GPIOs this manages (`N` to `N+ngpio-1`)

In your case the lowest `N` is `225`. **No chip manages GPIO `17`.** Invoke

```
cat /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip225/ngpio
```

If you get (e.g.) `2` then you can use two numbers: `225` and `226`:

```
# as root
echo 225 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo 226 > /sys/class/gpio/export
```

(If you want to use `sudo`, [this trick](https://superuser.com/a/1217399/432690) will be useful: `echo 225 | sudo tee /sys/class/gpio/export`).

Similarly for other controllers (`gpiochipN` entries).

---

Note `sysfs-gpio` is deprecated. See [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76j3TIqTPTI).

Comment: thank you echo 225 > /sys/class/gpio/export this is working without an error. But another problem. Im trying to do in this [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/robotics-development-kit-blink-led-tutorial) But when I run that code this error occurs: Failed to open gpio direction for writing! Could you please control that link

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I think I have solved your original problem. If you have a new one, ask a separate question (separate post). Please take our short [tour] to learn how the site works. Don't let this question be "[chameleon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/355310)".

Comment: okay. thank you so much I will  ask it in a new post.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Do the research first, especially what the documentation says about "direction". Make sure you understand the code from your link. Super User is not about programming and nobody will analyze the code.

Comment: Okey. I will delete the post and I will do research but can you please take a short look at that

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk There problem is with opening `/sys/class/gpio/gpioN/direction`. Maybe it doesn't exist. That's why I sent you back to the documentation where it describes `direction`.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Note `225` may or may not be right for what you're trying to do. It may be input-only or not available (physically) at all. Try to match `ngpio` from available controllers to numbers of physical pins (e.g. if there is a separate block of 20 pins, it's probably managed by a controller for which `ngpio` is `20`).

Comment: I have understood my problem now. I dont have an available gpiochip* file for my upboard. My upboard has 40 pins and the gpiochip files in /sys/class/gpio is not for the 40 pins how can I install an available driver for my upboard