# silence echo without output to terminal

Tags: bash, shell, echo

*"NON-Compliance - PermitRootLogin"* printed into output.log & test1.txt. I do **NOT** want to echo to the terminal. How can I do that?

```
  echo "NON-Compliance - PermitRootLogin" | tee output.log test1.txt
```

Terminal: NON-Compliance - PermitRootLogin

Answer (score 1):

In the original title you wrote "silence echo", you also used the tag [echo](/questions/tagged/echo), but what you see in the terminal does not directly come from `echo` you invoked. Your command looks like this:

```
echo … | tee …
```

In general `echo` prints to its stdout. `echo` does not print to anywhere else. `echo` does not print to the terminal unless the terminal is its stdout. In your command `echo` prints to a pipe and `tee` reads from the pipe. This `echo` does not print to the terminal.

In general `tee` prints to files passed as operands *and* to its stdout. In your case its stdout is the terminal, this (not `echo`) is what you want to silence. You have two options:

1. Either redirect stdout of `tee` to one of the files instead of specifying the file as an operand:

   ```
   … | tee output.log >test1.txt
   ```
2. Or redirect stdout of `tee` to `/dev/null` (it's a file that discards everything written to it):

   ```
   … | tee output.log test1.txt >/dev/null
   ```

   <sup>(Redirecting stdout and/or stderr to `/dev/null` is a basic *general* way to make a command silent.)</sup>

---

There's a subtle difference between the two. In the first case the shell creates (if needed), truncates and opens `test1.txt` before `tee` is started. In the second case `tee` does all this.

There are cases when the difference matters. Imagine you need `sudo tee …` because `test1.txt` cannot be accessed by the regular user who runs the shell. In this case `>test1.txt` wouldn't work. In fact `sudo tee some_file >/dev/null` is a [useful trick to write to `some_file` that requires root access](https://superuser.com/a/1217399/432690).