# bash script to write 2 random items to a file

Tags: linux, bash

I need a bash script to select 2 random nameservers from a list.  This is what I have that is not working - I get an error on the line `"$(($RANDOM % ${SIZE}))"` and I can't figure out why.

```
NAMESERVERS="x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x"
SIZE=${#NAMESERVERS[@]}
# select 2 random entries
NS_IDX=$(($RANDOM % ${SIZE}))
NS_IDX2=${NS_IDX1}
while [ "${NS_IDX1}" == "${NS_IDX2}" ]
do
   NS_IDX2=$(($RANDOM % ${IDX_RANGE}))
done
NS_IP1=${NAMESERVERS[${NX_IDX1}]}
NS_IP2=${NAMESERVERS[${NX_IDX2}]}
```

Then I echo NS_IP1 and NS_IP2 to /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I think the line `NS_IDX=$(($RANDOM % ${SIZE}))` is ok, `$SIZE` has a value and it isn't zero, but in the line `NS_IDX2=$(($RANDOM % ${IDX_RANGE}))`, `$IDX_RANGE` is null, this gives an error (maybe it has a value at that point). If you want `NAMESERVERS` as an array, declare it as `NAMESERVERS=(x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x)`. The `while` command is missing a closing `]`, maybe a typo?

Comment: "I get an error on the line" can you add the info about the error? What does the error say?

Comment: `${NX_IDX1}` and `${NX_IDX2}` are only used on the last two lines of your script?

Comment: @paulo - yes the missing ] in the while statement is a typo, sorry.

For the error, the message is "7: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "%81[@]"

I wonder if part of the problem is that the IP addresses are not being interpreted as IPs, but one character at a time.

Yes, i echo those ip's out to /etc/resolv.conf.   I could echo them out using "${NAMESERVERS[${NS_IDX1}]} "

Comment: Can you use [edit] to correct that typo ?

Comment: If you want to use `$RANDOM` then you need a shell that supports it. A proper shebang is advised, e.g. `#!/bin/bash -`. Unless you are sourcing the script in Bash in order to use the variables after the script finishes; if so, then the lack of shebang is fine.

Comment: Yes, I' using #! /bin/bash at the beginning of my script.

Comment: @kathyl Are you running the script with the `sh` command? If so, that overrides the shebang and runs it in plain sh, which probably doesn't have `$RANDOM`. Also, the assignment to `NAMESERVERS` is not creating an array, just a plain string with spaces; use `NAMESERVERS=(x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x x.x.x.x)` instead (the parentheses are what tells bash to make an array). I'd also recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) as a sanity-check. Finally, it's safest to use lower- or mixed-case variable names, to avoid conflicts with the many special all-caps vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use GNU `shuf` then a simple method is this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -
<<EOF shuf -n 2
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 9.9.9.9
nameserver 208.67.222.222
EOF
```

I embedded an example list of nameservers in the shell code as a here document. If you want to separate code from data, save the list as `nameservers` and then:

```
<nameservers shuf -n 2
```

xor

```
shuf -n 2 nameservers
```

Each of the above commands is so simple, that a person familiar with `shuf` may even prefer typing it on demand instead of creating a script.

Redirect the output to `/etc/resolv.conf` if this is what you want. Use [this trick with `tee`](https://superuser.com/a/1217399/432690) if you need `sudo`. Example:

```
# WARNING! This will overwrite your resolv.conf
<nameservers shuf -n 2 | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: That works for me - thank you!